# Azure webapp not updating certificate on keyvault

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I have a webapp running on Azure and it gets its SSL certificate from Keyvault.

I've updated the certificate on keyvault a week ago and the web app is still using the old one.

According to Azure doc, the webapp checks for new certificates regularly

Here is what I see on Azure KeyVault -> Certificates:
[image: Azure Keyvault]

Here is the certificate on my webapp:
[image: Certificate on webapp]

The certificate was attached with Azure ARM template:

```
{
  "type":"Microsoft.Web/certificates",
  "name":"[parameters('environmentConfiguration').Certificate]",
  "apiVersion":"2016-03-01",
  "location":"[resourceGroup().location]",
  "properties":{
      "keyVaultId":"[variables('keyVaultId')]",
      "keyVaultSecretName":"[parameters('environmentConfiguration').Certificate]",
      "serverFarmId": "[resourceId(variables('serverFarmResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('serverFarmName'))]"
  },
```

How to troubleshoot this kind of problems?

Comment: have you restarted your app ?

Comment: I've done it, and it still shows the old certificate

Answer (score 3):

The web app is still using the old one after you have updated a week ago. The possible cause is as below:

> The Web Apps feature of Azure App Service runs a background job
>   every eight hours and syncs the certificate resource if there are any
>   changes. When you rotate or update a certificate, sometimes the
>   application is still retrieving the old certificate and not the newly
>   updated certificate. The reason is that the job to sync the
>   certificate resource hasn't run yet.

Solution:

You can force a sync of the certificate. select the certificate from App Service Certificates.Select **Rekey and Sync**, and then select **Sync**. The sync takes some time to finish.When the sync is completed, you see the following notification: "Successfully updated all the resources with the latest certificate."

### Update

Please verify if the configuration of the new certificate is correct referring to [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/201-web-app-certificate-from-key-vault/).

Please check the Prerequisites, Deploying Key Vault Certificate into Web App, Rotating Certificate referring this blog: [deploying Azure Web App Certificate through Key Vault.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/05/24/deploying-azure-web-app-certificate-through-key-vault/)

Comment: Thanks Nancy, but the certificate is in KeyVault and is binded to the webapp with ARM templates. I have no certificates in App Service Certificates.

Comment: @Swell, would you like to verify your certificate status according to this 
 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/02/20/troubleshooting-tools-for-app-service-certificate/

Comment: I'm not using AppService Certificate at all, I manually upload the certificate to KeyVault and link the certificate to the AppService via ARM. I've updated my post.

Comment: @Swell, I have an update for you, please let me know if it does work.

Comment: @NancyXiong-MSFT I have this same issue. I think the crux could be understanding the scope of the 'automatic' updates. Is the periodic job only responsible for updating the Certificate Resource on the RP? ie: Does it only automate the task of doing `PUT /.../myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/myCert`?? If so, then we are still responsible for updating the SSL Bindings on the App Service to use the new Thumbprint?

Comment: @NancyXiong-MSFT not at all.

Comment: Updating the Certificate in the Vault does not trigger any automatic platform updates. However, once you re-`PUT` the Certificate in the Location+ResourceGroup+AppServicePlan, eventually** any dependent App Services will be updated. **In our case this took between 1-2 hours.